# Asyncio total number of tasks to be completed is always len+1

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Given the following Python snippet, I can't figure why the task count is always len+1.

```
async def do_something():
   ret = await my_routine()
   missing = f'Items to completion: {len(asyncio.all_tasks())}'
   print(missing)
   return ret


task = asyncio.ensure_future(do_something)
```

What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure you have shown correct code? You are using `await` not in `async def` function.

Comment: `do_something` is also a task

Comment: @AndrejKesely just mocked up the one above. There is an async in front of the def in the full code

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest gotcha. I thought tasks would have been solely those that were explicitly added via the method. Would that be safe doing a len-1 then? Or is there any better way?

Comment: A better way to achieve what?

Comment: @mkrieger1 a better way to count items, e.g. cherry picking those that have a name with a pattern or similar sort of things.